# How to send a file to another process via shared memory in C

Tags: c, shared-memory

I want to pass a file eg:hello.txt file to another process for reading that process should be able to read that file. So far I have only been able to send strings and such and I know that I can use fopen() to read the file and send data in a structure but other than that is there any way I can directly pass a file or copy it to the shared memory segment in order to read it in another process.

Comment: If you can send strings, send the full file spec.  The other process can then open it.

Comment: can you maybe link something that i can read upon

Comment: Is this process already running? Do you just pass command line arguments? Does the other process need write access to data? ...

Comment: The other process can just open the file itself. It doesn't need to be shared memory. It possibly canoe,  if both processes `mmap` the file.

Comment: i figured that my best option is to send the file names as an array to the shared memory and get a file descriptor from there but iam having trouble updating the array.is there a way to create a updatable array in shared memory?

Comment: First you spoke of only _a file_, now of a plurality of _file names as an array_ and moreover of _updating the array._ You should formulate a consistent question in the question post, and you should explain why you insist on using shared memory rather than a more suitable IPC method.